# Get-Website issue with -ne Not Equals

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, windows-server-2003

So I am trying to get a rather simple script to work but have not been successful.  All I am attempting to do is get the name of the other website we have on servers that does not equal `Default Web Site`.  I am aware of the `Get-Website` bug with the `-Name` and have tried all the workarounds without success.  Everything writes 'Default Web Site'  I'm stumped.  I should mention I need this done on 2003 servers with IIS6 using PS 2.0.

Here is what I'ved tried:

```
$site = Get-Website | Where {$_.Name -ne 'Default Web Site'}
$sitname = $site
Write-Host $sitename
```

and

```
$site = Get-Website | Where {$_.Name -ne '*Default Web Site*'}
$sitname = $site
Write-Host $sitename
```

and

```
$site = Get-Item "IIS:\sites" | where {$_.Name -ne 'Default Web Site'}
$sitname = $site
Write-Host $sitename
```

and

```
$site = Get-Item "IIS:\sites" | where {$_.Name -ne '*Default Web Site*'}
$sitname = $site
Write-Host $sitename
```

I've even tried changing `-ne 'Default Web Site'` to `-eq 'Second Site Name` to see what happens and it still just gives me the Default Web site output.

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm I still a victim of a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code after I had managed to figure this out.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$getnames = Get-Website | Where {$_.Name -like 'oldsite.com'}|select-object Name
$sitenames = $getnames.name
Write-Host $sitenames
$itemproperty = "IIS:\Sites\" + $sitenames
Set-ItemProperty $itemproperty -name Name -value Newwebsite.com
Write-Host $sitenames + "has been renamed to Newwebsite.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on line 2. `$sitname` should be `$sitename` (missing an `e` in the middle). Correct code:

```
$site = Get-Website | Where {$_.Name -ne 'Default Web Site'}
$sitename = $site
Write-Host $sitename
```

But, `Get-Website` doesn't just return a string - it returns a `Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement`. To get just the site *names*, you need to do the following:

```
$sitenames = Get-Website | Where {$_.Name -ne 'Default Web Site'}|select-object Name
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that.  I used your suggestion and the output looks like this: @{name=NewTest}
How do I get it to display like this: NewTest

Comment: Is that the output you got with my last bit of code (the one-liner)?

Comment: Correct, the exact output after running your code and doing a write-host is: `@{name=Newtest`

Comment: Which code? I gave you 2 different things. I cannot reproduce what you're reporting here - the last example I gave (the one-liner) gives the output one would expect - a list of site names, not a text representation of a collection.

Comment: `$sitenames = Get-Website | Where {$_.Name -ne 'Default Web Site'}|select-object Name
Write-Host $sitenames`

Comment: I am trying to get the name of the website that is not the Default so I can rename it.  The website name is not static between servers so I need to have the PS script pull that info.  I can't pass the current output as I get this error:
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'IIS:\Sites\@{name=NewTest}' because it does not exist.

Here is the code I am using:
`$sitename = Get-Website | Where {$_.Name -ne 'Default Web Site'}|select-object Name
Write-Host $sitename
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$sitename" -name Name -value Newwebsitename
Write-Host ''$sitename' has been renamed to Newwebsitename'`

Comment: I was able to get this to work for reference.  I had to change a few things in order to get it the way I needed it but here is the code:

`Import-Module WebAdministration
$getnames = Get-Website | Where {$_.Name -like 'oldsite.com'}|select-object Name
$sitenames = $getnames.name
Write-Host $sitenames
$itemproperty = "IIS:\Sites\" + $sitenames
Set-ItemProperty $itemproperty -name Name -value Newwebsite.com
Write-Host $sitenames + "has been renamed to Newwebsite.com"`